# Apache Spark - write only the changed partitions

Tags: apache-spark, data-partitioning

Is there a ***built-in*** way to define a `DataFrame` as a set of partition paths (each with one or more files), use that `DataFrame` as the basis of a set of so-called "mutation" queries which are defined as a separate `DataFrame`, and partition the resulting `DataFrame` by the same columns, only writing the "changed" partitions (i.e. only those partitions where the data is different between the original `DataFrame` and the resulting `DataFrame`)?

This would be for "dimension" data, of course.

The whole point is to reduce total storage by re-using partition files that haven't changed. Perhaps storage is cheap enough that this is pointless. Nevertheless, it would be good to know.

Obviously there's ways to do this by specifying a series of transforms myself:

1. `{original DataFrame} -> o`
2. `{resulting DataFrame -> r`
3. `{*, COUNT(o.*) GROUP BY *} -> o2`
4. `{*, COUNT(r.*) GROUP BY *} -> r2`
5. `{DISTINCT [partition columns] FROM o2 FULL JOIN r2 ON [partition columns] WHERE o2.* IS NULL OR r2.* IS NULL}`

I can't tell if there would be any shuffling in the general case. Given that the `JOIN` is on partition columns and that's how the original and resulting `DataFrame`s are both partitioned, perhaps there would be none.

Comment: [Slowly changing dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) can be implemented in Spark, but if you're interested in mutation, just go with proper database. Overwriting storage as a part of the logic is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: This isn't overwriting storage... I still have the original `DataFrame` partition files. I just have a new `DataFrame` that shares storage with the original `DataFrame`, so I cut down on disk space utilization.